# Moving file contents into an array

Tags: arrays, vb.net

Im currently working on getting this piece of code to work so that I can read a text file, move the contents into an array and then display a certain column (such as price)

```
Imports System.IO
Public Class Form1
Dim FileName As String
Dim i As Integer = 0
Dim Alpha As Integer = 0
Dim Products(31) As String

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    FileName = "Products.txt"
End Sub
Private Sub btnCreateArray_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnCreateArray.Click
    Using MyReader As New Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.TextFieldParser("Products.txt")
        MyReader.TextFieldType = FileIO.FieldType.Delimited
        MyReader.SetDelimiters(",")
        Dim currentRow As String()

        While Not MyReader.EndOfData
            currentRow = MyReader.ReadFields()
            Dim currentField As String
            For Each currentField In currentRow
                'MsgBox(currentField)
                'txtShowNo.Text = currentField
                'txtShowP.Text = i
                i = i + 1
                Products(i) = currentField
            Next
        End While
    End Using
    Do While Alpha <= i
        If InStr((txtFileSearch.Text), (Products(Alpha))) Then
            lstDisplayFile.Items.Add(Products(Alpha))
            Alpha = Alpha + 1
        End If
    Loop
End Sub
Private Sub btn_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btn.Click
    txtFileSearch.Text = ""
End Sub
Private Sub btnAddToFilePrintFile_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnAddToFilePrintFile.Click
    Dim Name As String
    Dim SName As String
    Dim IDNo As Integer
    Name = txtName.Text
    SName = txtSName.Text
    IDNo = txtIDNo.Text
    FileOpen(1, FileName, OpenMode.Append)          ' create a new empty file & open it in append mode'
    WriteLine(1, IDNo, Name, SName)                         ' Writes a line of data'
    FileClose(1)
    txtName.Text = ""
    txtSName.Text = ""
    txtIDNo.Text = ""
    txtName.Focus()
End Sub
End Class
```

The program crashes on this line of code:

```
lstDisplayFile.Items.Add(Products(Alpha))
```

along with the following message :

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentNullException' occurred in System.Windows.Forms.dll
```

Alpha is my counter, and my thought process behind this was that if the input within the textbox is currently in the array, it will display the completed text in the array.
Here is the current contents within my text file :

1. "£5.00","50"
2. "£2.50","30"

If anyone could help me solve this I would be appreciative :)

Comment: Set a breakpoint in both of your loops, debug the code and you´ll find the answer by yourself. Btw...why bother with arrays? Use as generic List or Dictionary. This will save you alot of pain.

Comment: what's lstDistplayFile? can't find it

Comment: You never declare lstDisplayFile, or is it a public var? if so, can you post how you declare it?

Comment: It's a listbox that in trying to display my text in